# Request with status:401 and popup message fails

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cypress, assert

Have assertion with 401 request, which passes, but want, also, to confirm popup error which appears (that part fails). Below are screenshots of page layout and test results:

[image]

[image]

And code which wrote:

```
it('should not be loaded any data without mocks', () => {
cy.visit('/partURL');
cy.server();
cy.route({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '**/forms?workspace?**',
}).as('myUrlAlias');
cy.wait('@myUrlAlias')
  .its('status')
  .should('eq', 401);
 cy.get('div.inner_page__content div.embedded_alert__wrapper img')
  .should('have.attr', 'src')
  .and('include', 'alt');
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try using `div.inner_page__content > div.embedded_alert__wrapper > img`.

Comment: @AlapanDas Unfortunately, same result.

Comment: Hi @Zoran Would it possible to see the dom structure of the pop up ?

Comment: @AlapanDas It looks to me, that before even go to assert step, it finishes test, and look on different page. But not sure how to fix it to first assert element and later opens another page and thank you for helping me

Comment: @AlapanDas Added screenhot for DOM

Comment: can you add a bit of wait `cy.wait(5000)` before the img assert and give it a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224787/discussion-between-alapan-das-and-zoran).

Comment: @AlapanDas It does not help either, I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me your chain on the target element is wrong. `.and()` [checks for assertion on the original element](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/and.html#Usage), if you wana check the attr - you should chain a second [.should()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html). Here an alternative idea:

```
it('should not be loaded any data without mocks', () => {
    cy.visit('/partURL');
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '**/forms?workspace?**',
    }).as('myUrlAlias');
    cy.wait('@myUrlAlias')
        .its('status')
        .should('eq', 401);
    cy.get('img[alt="Warning icon"]')
        .should('exist')
});
```